# VB.Net Copy Method in Excel "Copy method of Worksheet class failed"

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have a problem in method Copy in Excel.
I want to copy and insert existed sheet in workbook, i used Copy method.
When Method Copy have parameter (Before:= , After:=), "Copy method of Worksheet class failed" error occur.

This is my code

report.WorkSheet(1).Copy(Before:=report.WorkSheet(2), After:=report.WorkSheet(3))

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: I think the problem should be "2 args", it should be 1 argument instead. `report.WorkSheet(1).Copy(After:=report.WorkSheet(1))` Before refers to insert before (left side of) this particular worksheet, after refers to insert after (right side of) this particular worksheet.

Comment: I used 2 arg but nothing changes

Comment: Because you aren't supposed to use 2 args. the argument should be the (the place where you want to insert your Worksheet(1).Copy data.

Comment: I just try with 1 arg but the error is occuring.
It throw exception: "index was outside the bounds of the array"

Comment: The problem must be you have only 1 worksheet.